# How to execute FIND Rest API call in Appery.io

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, appery.io

Currently I am working on an app which is being developed using `Cordova` and `Appery.io`. I want to make `Find` api call in `user` table. But it always gives me `StatusCode:400` it means Bad request. Here is my URL for this api call

> 'https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/users?where=`{"username":"suryajeet.singh@mobiloittegroup.com"}'`

Any idea what I am doing wrong to make this api call? Quick response will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use database master key to query `Users` collection, see
https://docs.appery.io/docs/database-settings

```
curl -X GET \
   -H "X-Appery-Database-Id: 57928860e4b00ef864f3dc24" \
   -H "X-Appery-Master-Key: 7ec7f59e-475d-49ba-a2d1-fc22df51eb55" \
   -G --data-urlencode 'where={"username":"suryajeet.singh@mobiloittegroup.com"} \
   https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/users
```

More info can be found at https://docs.appery.io/reference#database-api-user